# Inline images and Clears on Wordpress Page

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

SO,

I'm building a page where I'd like to have a few words of text (such as "contact us") followed by an image or icon on the same line. I've been able to achieve this effect in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5hpS/3/), but when I transfer the same CSS and HTML to WordPress, my text and my image are always on separate lines, as you can see [here](http://lrgi.org/?page_id=20). I can't figure out what is preventing the text and image from remaining on the same line. I thought I'd disabled autop by adding this code to my theme's functions.php file:

```
// Remove WordPress Auto P
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
// Auto P is also called in these filters, I'm just adding these lines for your information.
// If you want to disable them, uncomment
// remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
// remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
// remove_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop' ); // <-- Be careful with this one
```

But maybe I was wrong. I'm embarrassed to have been stumped by what seems like such a simple problem, but I'm hoping someone out there can shed some light on this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Marca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
.bodyheadtext {
  float: left;
}
```

*Or* remove `float: left` from `.bodyhead`.